# Probability of running out of tosses

Tags: probability

Fix some positive integer $x>1$. If I toss coins until I get $\sqrt{x}$ heads where the first toss gets a head with probability $1/x$, the second with $2/x$, the third with $3/x$  etc., what is the probability of getting to the $x$th toss before having found $\sqrt{x}$ heads ? The process just stops if you do ever get to the $x$th toss.

Comment: you are using $n$ with two meanings: the number of tosses and the probability of the first toss (1/n). Could you clarify?

Comment: It's not clear when you say: "each toss gets a head with probability $1/n$". So the probability of a head is not 50%? It depends on the number of tosses?

Comment: Do you want a closed form for finite $x$, or asymptotics? The probability rapidly goes to zero for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @joriki Thank you for your answer.  Tail bounds are OK although it would be nice to know the exact answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H$ be the number of heads and $H_k$ the indicator variable for heads in the $k$-th toss. The expected value of the number of heads after $x$ tosses is

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[H]
&=
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{k=1}^xH_k\right]
\\
&=
\sum_{k=1}^x\mathbb E[H_k]
\\
&=
\sum_{k=1}^x\frac kx
\\
&=\frac{x+1}2\;.
\end{align}
$$

The expected value of the square of the number of heads is

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[H^2]
&=
\mathbb E\left[\left(\sum_{k=1}^xH_k\right)^2\right]
\\
&=
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{j=1}^x\sum_{k=1}^xH_jH_k\right]
\\
&=
\sum_{j=1}^x\sum_{k=1}^x\mathbb E\left[H_jH_k\right]
\\
&=
\sum_{j=1}^x\sum_{k=1}^x\frac{jk}{x^2}+\sum_{k=1}^x\left(\frac kx-\frac{k^2}{x^2}\right)
\\
&=
\mathbb E[H]^2+\frac{x+1}2-\frac{(x+1)(2x+1)}{6x}
\\
&=
\mathbb E[H]^2+\frac{x^2-1}{6x}\;,
\end{align}
$$

so the variance is $(x^2-1)/(6x)$. Since both the expected value and the variance go as $x$, the probability that the number of heads is less than $\sqrt x$ goes to zero exponentially as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Can you expand the last sentence please. Is this a known theorem you are using?